# Javafx greedy binding

Tags: javafx

According to the sample code below  Java FX Bindings seem to be non-greedy by default.

```java
assertEquals(2,calledEffect);
```

does not work
but

```java
assertEquals(2,keepBinding.get())
```

does.

**How could I make sure the Binding is automatically activated - getting a greedy behavior?**

```java
long calledEffect=0;
private LongBinding keepBinding;
public long callMe(long value) {
  calledEffect=value+1;
  return calledEffect;
}

@Test
public void testBinding() {
  SimpleLongProperty lp = new SimpleLongProperty(); 
  lp.setValue(4711);
  keepBinding=Bindings.createLongBinding(()->callMe(lp.get()),lp);
  lp.setValue(1);
  //assertEquals(2,calledEffect);
  assertEquals(2,keepBinding.get());
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bindings are computed only when you need to get their value. If you want to invoke code whenever the value changes, use a change listener:

```
lp.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> callMe(newValue));
```

Your code then needs to be changed to:

```
long calledEffect=0;
private LongBinding keepBinding;
public long callMe(Number newValue) {
  calledEffect=newValue.longValue()+1;
  return calledEffect;
}

@Test
public void testBinding() {
  SimpleLongProperty lp = new SimpleLongProperty(); 
  lp.setValue(4711);
  keepBinding=Bindings.createLongBinding(()->callMe(lp.get()),lp);
  lp.addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> callMe(newValue));
  lp.setValue(1);
  assertEquals(2,calledEffect);
  assertEquals(2,keepBinding.get());
}
```